# What's the `esb` , and how can I realize the asynchronous data function?

Tags: database, architecture, esb

When I reading a document, there is a image:

**Asynchronous double writing service**

[image]

I don'w know what's the `esb` here, I think it should be a service for asynchronous the data.

I want know how can I realize the Asynchronous data to the DB-T2?

Answer (score 0):

ESB = [Enterprise Service Bus](https://www.mulesoft.com/resources/esb/what-esb), basically a system for enterprise messaging (Message Queues, workers, transformers, topics, etc).

To realize this you will have to hook your service up to the ESB (methodology depends on the ESB vendor, and the service language/framework).  You will also need a connector from the ESB message queue to the DB2 inside the data-center.  Most ESBs have database connectors baked in, and simply require configuration for the mapping to the table structures.